# Classification of individual values with matrix

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have a series of matrices 30x30 matrices that contain elements ranging from 0 to 75 (input matrices) and each one has a 30x30 matrix containing only 1s and 0s (output matrices). I am trying to train a classifier on the input matrices to predict the output matrices, however I am not sure how to best represent the input matrices for the classifier (ideally sk-learn). I can't abstract the matrices to another form as each element from the input matrix must map to the element in the same location of the output matrix. Has anyone tried to something similar?

Comment: can you give an example of input, expected output and what have you tried?

Comment: You should look at numpy array and its significance in sk-learn's fit method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1: Multi label classifier

- You can flatten the `30X30` matrix into a `900` element vector and feed it to a neural network for multi label classification 
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification
- Treat `30X30` matrix as a single channel image and model a CNN with proper loss function for multi label classification.

### Option 2: Sequence to Sequence classifier

- Flatten the `30X30` matrix into a `900` element vector and build a LSTM with 900 timesteps with ith element in the vector being input to ith timestep. The LSTM is connected to a Dense layer with sigmoid activation (2 class classification). If you use keras for implementaiton you will have to use `return_sequence=True` for this.